# Ninject and Assembly Bindings in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, ninject, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, assemblybinding

I have an Azure Function that is relying on other assemblies which in turn relies on Ninject for dependency injection. During runtime, Ninject seems to fail to resolve a dependency for some custom `Ninject.Activation.Provider<T>`, resulting in a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

The Ninject part of the stack-trace is:

> at Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
>      at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service,IContext parent)
>      at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context,ITarget target)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2(ITarget target)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(O…

The dependency not resolved is to `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` (or one of it's dependencies). It's included into the project via NuGet.

This assembly in question however, does actually exist on disk in the bin folder of the Azure Function, and the build itself is fine. My theory, therefore, is that Ninject does something peculiar when instantiating the custom `Provider<T>`.

Maybe Ninject expects the dependencies to be gathered at another location, relative to where the Function executes or something? Maybe it's not Ninject at all that is to be blamed, but rather some particular when it comes to how dependencies are resolved in the Azure environment that I'm unaware of?

I'm hoping that one of you can help me out by shedding light on what's going on here, or suggest a smart troubleshooting move, 'cause I've drawn all blanks for a couple of days now.

If that's the case to be, I can influence how the people responsible for the custom `Provider<T>` addresses things in their code, so possible solutions include this venue.

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: could you paste some code please ? it will be easier for us to reproduce. Also do you really need DI ?

Comment: DI is a good thing, and personally I would never want to be without it, but in this case it's out of my hands, really. As to "really need", um, "no"? But even so, a major re-write of the code base to me wouldn't really be a "solution" :) Furthermore, I don't see how DI as a principal can be the issue here.

Comment: I have no minimum-code-to-reproduce to give you, sorry to say. The actual solution consists of 15-20 projects and hundreds of thousands of lines of code, and extracting the bare minimum would take a lot of work. I was hoping to not have to do that in order to find a solution, but if I get no answers, maybe I'll have to.

Comment: I mean for functions (serverless) DI could be an overkill. But if you're using existing code base I understand. If we can't reproduce it, it will be difficult. Have you tried create an empty azure function project and reproduce the problem while injecting dummy classes ? Are you sure the System.Web.Mvc assembly is referenced in your project ? Is it a binding assembly redirect problem ?

Comment: Which version of azure function you are using?